# jquery delay doesn't count as animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to do an animation after button click using promises. But no matter what I do, it will still let me keep clicking.

I'm showing some Bootstrap form validator classes and then removing them. Like this:

```
messageEffect : function(container) {
                return container.fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut();
            },

$.when(this.messageEffect($container)).done(function() { 
                    $container.empty();
                    $icon.remove();
                    $group.removeClass('has-feedback has-' + alertType);
                });
```

I'm calling this function called "showAlert()" after some stuff, if something fails, I show the error message below the input field.

Thing is, if I keep clicking and clicking, it will spam the message spans, until they disappear (of course) due to the animation.

I tried using the `('div-that-is-animating').is(':animated')` but didn't work, I can still spam them.

I also tried doing an unbind of toggle and click before calling this "showAlert()" function, but didn't work either.

Is it because delay(1000) there isn't counting like an animation? Or what else I can try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works (assuming your button id is `myButton`):

```
messageEffect : function(container) {
                $('#myButton').attr('disabled', true);
                return container.fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut();
            },

$.when(this.messageEffect($container)).done(function() { 
                    $('#myButton').attr('disabled', false);
                    $container.empty();
                    $icon.remove();
                    $group.removeClass('has-feedback has-' + alertType);
                });
```